# My right arm looks slightly bigger than the left arm

Tags: bodybuilding

Although I train my arms equally, my right arm looks slightly more trained and muscular than the left arm, also my right arm feels tired after training in contrast to my left arm, what's the solution to make both look the same?!

Answer (score 2):

Naturally, everybody has one dominant arm over the other. Odd are if you're right handed, you tend to do most tasks with that hand.  However an unwanted result can sometimes be exactly what you're experiencing, arms that are uneven in strength and appearance.

*The good news is that there are some ways to even them out. Be patient as they won't even out over night.*

---

### Ditch the Barbells

Barbells are an excellent mass builder. It may be true that they are excellent for building strength on power movements.  ***However they are a common cause of uneven arms***.

Barbells allow your stronger arm to take over the movement and you may not even realize it. Switch to dumbbells for all of your bicep and tricep exercises to allow each arm to be worked more evenly. For example, instead of barbell curls and tricep presses - do dumbbell curls and dumbbell presses.

---

### Work Each Arm Separately

Building on the previous tip, **not all exercises are done with a barbell but that doesn't mean your arms are being worked evenly**. Exercises like machine preacher curls and tricep pushdowns don't use a barbell but still work both arms at the same time which means that one arm can dominate. For these exercises, you should work each arm separately to ensure that one arm isn't doing more work.

---

### Weaker Arm First

When working your arms separately, it's important to start with your weaker arm first. This way, you know when to stop with your stronger arm so you're doing equal work with each arm. The whole point of working your arms separately is to ensure you get an equal work out with each arm. If you do more with your stronger arm this defeats the purpose.

---

### Work Each Arm Equally

**This is probably the most important tip.** Some people try doing extra sets with their weaker arm or do more weight and more reps. This isn't a good idea. You should use the same weight for the same reps and same sets or else you may end up over training one side and under training the other. **Select a weight that your weak arm can handle** for the selected amount of reps and do the same weight with your strong arm too. Over time, they will even out.

---

### Use Your Weaker Arm More

This may seem odd, but try to use your weaker arm for some more everyday activities. Open doors, carry groceries, drink water, eat meals, etc. with your weaker arm. It will help you become more comfortable using your weaker arm and over time will help you become more comfortable using it in the gym which will improve your neuromuscular efficiency.

---

**Sources**

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16972050
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15335243
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12436270
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17241104

Answer (score 0):

No human body has perfect symmetry. It is normal. I would train them both the same.